# Obtener los datos de una tabla pivote en show

Tags: laravel

Tengo una tabla pivote y se sincroniza de manera correcta en `UPDATE` con `$profile->availability()->sync($request->get('availability'));` pero ahora necesito mostrar en `SHOW` donde los datos de dicha tabla pivote y no sé como, lo intenté con `$profile->availability();` y `$profile->availability()->sync();` pero no obtengo los datos.

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $profile = Profile::where('user_id', $id)->first();

        $photo = Photo::where('user_id', $id)->first();

        $user = User::find($id);

        $profile->availability()->sync($request->get('availability')); // Aquí muestra error porque no recibo datos con el parametro $request.

        return view('profiles.show', compact('profile', 'user', 'photo')); 
    }
```

Comment: Eloquent ubica los datos de la tabla pivote bajo el atributo `pivot` de la relación. Puedes leer más en la [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns).

Comment: Ayudaría mucho indiques el mensaje de error que obtienes